# Scrolling a UITableView with easeOut

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I can scroll a UITableView to top by setting its contentOffset to zero. i.e.

```
  [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
```

But I want an ease-out effect and slow scrolling. So I am using

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

or

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                    delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
               animations:^{
                 [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
               } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

               }];
```

the scrolling works well , but the content isn't visible until scrolling ends or the tableView starts decelarating.
Any solutions??

Comment: what happend with this code?

Comment: the scrolling works well , but the content isn't visible until scrolling ends or the tableView starts decelarating. i.e. the tableview goes blank and scrolls up and then content is visible